# How to deserialize class without calling a constructor?

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I'm using Json.NET in my WCF data service.

Here's my class (simplified):

```
[DataContract]
public class Component
{
    public Component()
    {
        // I'm doing some magic here.
    }
}
```

How can I deserialize that class *without* invoking a constructor using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`?

Sorry if not clear, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Not possible AFAIK. A constructor is always executed when creating an instance.

Comment: @Maarten http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getsafeuninitializedobject.aspx

Comment: Thanx! I learned something today :-)

Comment: You can add an `Initialize` method with your logic. That requires a consuming code change unfortunately.

Comment: @SteveB: Initialization methods fails if someone forgets to call them (or don't understand that they have to be called)

Comment: @jgauffin: you are right. Your solution is better, but what about if there is no parameter to pass to the constructor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You could create a class that inherits from `CustomCreationConverter`
   and use `FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject` to create your
   object. It skips calling the constructor.

   More about CustomCreationConverter [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomCreationConverter.htm).
2. Placing
   `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]` on a class will make Json.NET use
   `FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject` by default (although
   Fields mode will also serialize public/private fields rather than
   public properties which you may not want).
3. Move the logic you don't want run outside of the default constructor.

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason, when I tried `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]`, it produced `StackOverflowException`. So I prefer first variant. Can you please tell me - is there a way to create universal `CustomCreationConverter` for many classes?

Comment: Copy the CustomCreationConverter source code and modify it to do what you want. It just inherits from JsonConverter - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs

Answer (score 12):

A constructor is always invoked. I usually have two  constructors. One for serialization (the default constructor) and one for all "regular" code:

```
[DataContract]
public class Component
{
    // for JSON.NET
    protected Component()
    {
    }

    public Component(allMandatoryFieldsHere)
    {
        // I'm doing some magic here.
    }
}
```

In that way I can also make sure that the dev specify all information which are required.

However, I do not really recommend that you use anything but DTO's when transfering information since it's otherwise possible to circumvent the encapsulation of your objects (anyone could initialize any field with any value). Well. If you use anything but anemic models.

Using `FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject` is imho therefore an ugly workaround, since no one can tell that you create all objects in an unintialized way. Constructor initialization is there for a reason. It's better that the classes can tell that it's OK to not call the real constructor by providing a "serialization" constructor as I suggested.

Comment: But as far as I know, default `DataContractJsonSerializer` doesn't invoke a constructor.

Comment: @IgorShastin: That's why you only should use it with DTO's. JSON.NET is more well behaving.

Answer (score 3):

Others already mentioned the second constructor, but using 2 attributes: [JsonConstructor] and [Obsolete] you can do much better than leaving it up to humans to remember which one to call.

```
    public ChatMessage()
    {   
        MessageID = ApplicationState.GetNextChatMessageID(); // An expensive call that uses up an otherwise free ID from a limited set and does disk access in the process.
    }


    [JsonConstructor] // This forces JsonSerializer to call it instead of the default.
    [Obsolete("Call the default constructor. This is only for JSONserializer", true)] // To make sure that calling this from your code directly will generate a compiler error. JSONserializer can still call it because it does it via reflection.
    public ChatMessage(bool DO_NOT_CALL_THIS)
    {
    }
```

[JsonConstructor] forces JsonSerializer to call it instead of the default.
[Obsolete("...", true)] Makes sure that calling this from your code directly will generate a compiler error. JSONserializer can still call it because it does it via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

The best option to avoid constructor calls on deserialization is to create special contract resolver that overrides creator function for all classes without constructor marked with JsonConstructor attribute. This way you still can force JSON.NET to call constructor if you really need it, but all other classes will be created much like in standard DataContract serializers in .NET. Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Special contract resolver to create objects bypassing constructor call.
/// </summary>
public class NoConstructorCreationContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract"/> for the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract"/> for the given type.
    /// </returns>
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        // prepare contract using default resolver
        var objectContract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        // if type has constructor marked with JsonConstructor attribute or can't be instantiated, return default contract
        if (objectContract.OverrideCreator != null || objectContract.CreatedType.IsInterface || objectContract.CreatedType.IsAbstract)
            return objectContract;

        // prepare function to check that specified constructor parameter corresponds to non writable property on a type
        Func<JsonProperty, bool> isParameterForNonWritableProperty =
            parameter =>
            {
                var propertyForParameter =
                    objectContract.Properties.FirstOrDefault(property => property.PropertyName == parameter.PropertyName);

                if (propertyForParameter == null)
                    return false;

                return !propertyForParameter.Writable;
            };

        // if type has parameterized constructor and any of constructor parameters corresponds to non writable property, return default contract
        // this is needed to handle special cases for types that can be initialized only via constructor, i.e. Tuple<>
        if (objectContract.CreatorParameters.Any(parameter => isParameterForNonWritableProperty(parameter)))
            return objectContract;

        // override default creation method to create object without constructor call
        objectContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false;
        objectContract.DefaultCreator = () => FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject(objectContract.CreatedType);

        return objectContract;
    }
}
```

All you need is simply set this contract resolver in serializer settings before deserialization.

**Update on readonly fields and get-only properties**

A readonly field can be deserialized if it has a JsonProperty attribute applied.
A get-only property can also be deserialized if it's backing field has a JsonProperty attribute applied.
Since C# 7.3 it's possible to apply attributes to compiler-generated backing fields of auto-properties.

Leveraging this we could do something like this:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [JsonProperty("Field1")]
    private readonly string _field1 = "Field1Value";

    [JsonProperty("Property1")]
    private string _property1BackingField = "Property1Value";

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Property1 => _property1BackingField;

    [field: JsonProperty("Property2")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Property2 { get; } = "Property2Value";
}

const string json = "{\"Field1\":\"NEW-Field1Value\",\"Property1\":\"NEW-Property1Value\",\"Property2\":\"NEW-Property2Value\"}";

var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        // this settings is needed to work with compiler-generated backing fields
        SerializeCompilerGeneratedMembers = true
    }
};

var deserializedSample = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(json, serializerSettings);
```

If you need to do this in older C# version or have no control over attributes, you could override CreateProperty() method of DefaultContractResolver with something like this:

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    var jsonProperty = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    if (jsonProperty.Writable == false)
    {
        // this uses compiler implementation details and may not work for all cases
        // better to use smarter approach like in BackingFieldResolver from Mono.Reflection library
        var fieldInfo = jsonProperty.DeclaringType.GetField($"<{jsonProperty.PropertyName}>k__BackingField",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (fieldInfo != null)
        {
            jsonProperty.ValueProvider = new ReflectionValueProvider(fieldInfo);
            jsonProperty.Writable = true;
        }
    }
        
    return jsonProperty;
}
```

Comment: The objectContract.OverrideConstructor property does not exists.

Comment: @flayn Yes, it has been changed to OverrideCreator. I've updated the snippet.

Comment: @Alexander Do you know how you would expand on this to allow the deserialization process also write to readonly marked properties?

Comment: @Erutan409 I've added ideas on readonly fields and get-only properties. Hope this helps.