# Json serdes override / customize base class construction

Tags: c#, json, constructor, deserialization, default-constructor

I have a deep object hierarchy where the base class parameterless constructor looks like this:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    private Session session_;
    public BaseClass()
    {
        session_ = ...;
    }
}
```

Serialization is OK. Problem happens in deserialization when the object construction tries to establish a connection to a webservice to construct the session object which is not necessary at all as all the values obtained from the session have been serialized. So the question is how do I customize / override the constructor to skip the deserialization of session field?

Comment: ^ In summary: Either write an explicit constructor for JSON.net to use, or implement your own (de)serialization logic

Comment: Or you can use `FormatterServices.GetSafeUninitializedObject` as is described in [How to deserialize class without calling a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947997/how-to-deserialize-class-without-calling-a-constructor).